# PHP (MySQLi) - Displaying Data in multiple locations

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, switch-statement, echo

I have a customer summary page on which I would like to display data from an SQL query in various locations which is currently failing when i try to display data in multiple parts of the page?

Any suggestions as to why?

In the head area:

```
<?php
// Database settings - data replaced with ######
$servername = "######";
$username = "#######";
$password = "#######";
$dbname = "#######";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
        // Build query and place into variable names SQL
        $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM cust_details
        INNER JOIN cust_details_contacts
        ON
        cust_details.cust_details_id = cust_details_contacts.cust_details_id
        WHERE
        cust_details.cust_details_id=73
        AND
        cust_details_contacts.cust_details_id = 73";
        // Open connection run query and place outcome in variable result
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        ?>
```

**In the main body - the following works and displays:**

```
<section class="content-header">
<h1>
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $row['cust_details_name']; ?>
</h1>
<?php include("global_breadcrumb.php"); ?>
</section>
```

**In another area of the main body - the following works and displays:**

```
<div class="box-body">
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo "<h1>" . $row['cust_details_legal'] . "</h1>";
echo "<p>Company Number&nbsp;" . $row['cust_details_company_no'] . "</p>";
?>
///more html content here...
</div>
```

**Further into the body - this then FAILS to display any data, unless I remove the above php sections and if i do remove the above only displays one of 3 recrods unless i remove the switch statement (also tried if else if instead of switch with same problem)**

```
<table class="table no-margin">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cust_details_contacts_forename'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cust_details_contacts_surname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cust_details_contacts_phone'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rpw['cust_details_contacts_email'] . "</td>";

//Also tried if ifelse statement neither worked

switch ($row['cust_details_contacts_type']) {
case "Key";
"<td><span class='label label-info'>". $row['cust_details_contacts_type'] . "</span></td>";
break;
case "Meters";
"<td><span class='label label-warning'>". $row['cust_details_contacts_type'] . "</span></td>";
break;
case "Accounts";
"<td><span class='label label-danger'>". $row['cust_details_contacts_type'] . "</span></td>";
break;  }                   
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Any solutions / constructive feedback greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance**

Comment: In the last section, and in the last echo you're setting $rpw instead of $row, this may not fix your problem but it's an error

Comment: Phiter. Ive checked the original source and its an error when I posted it not in the source. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set so that you could iterate through it again. Make use of `mysqli_data_seek()` function for this.

Here's the reference:

- [`mysqli_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
<table class="table no-margin">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Type</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php

    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); // adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cust_details_contacts_forename'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cust_details_contacts_surname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cust_details_contacts_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $rpw['cust_details_contacts_email'] . "</td>";

        switch ($row['cust_details_contacts_type']) {
            case "Key":
                echo "<td><span class='label label-info'>". $row['cust_details_contacts_type'] . "</span></td>";
                break;
            case "Meters":
                echo "<td><span class='label label-warning'>". $row['cust_details_contacts_type'] . "</span></td>";
                break;
            case "Accounts":
                echo "<td><span class='label label-danger'>". $row['cust_details_contacts_type'] . "</span></td>";
                break;  
        }                   
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Rajdeep, thank you so much it worked (partly)!     Three rows show now but the SWITCH statement does not.  Any thoughts?  Also, should i use the mysqli_data_seek every time i echo data in the document or only if I am using a while loop?

Comment: @Nathwales As per the documentation you can use `mysqli_data_seek()` function **anywhere** (not necessarily before a loop), where you think you need to adjusts the result pointer to an arbitrary row in the result set.

Comment: @Nathwales And for the switch-case statement, you didn't `echo` the strings, you just enclosed them in double quotes. Do `echo "<td><span ...</td>";`.

Comment: thank you for your feedback.  I did not understand your last comment with respect to the switch case statement where you said _"you didn't echo the strings, you just enclosed them in double quotes. Do _ `echo "<td><span ...</td>";`".   My statement is: `echo "<td><span class='label label-warning'>". $row['cust_details_contacts_type'] . "</span></td>";` is this incorrect? If so would you kindly comment the code as it should be? Thanks again.

Comment: @Nathwales Your statement looks good, but there's a typo error in `case` statements which I didn't notice earlier. `case "Key";` should be `case "Key":`, `case "Meters";` should be `case "Meters":` and so on. I've updated my answer. Also make sure that case labels are correct i.e `case "Key":` and `case "key":` are different.